# Continuity implies Lipschitzness in Frechet Spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Consider two Frechet spaces $(X,d_X),\;(Y,d_Y)$. Let $T:X \rightarrow Y$ be a continues linear operator. Is it true that $T$ is Lipschitz in the following sense:
$$\exists \alpha > 0 \; \forall x,y \in X \; d_Y(Tx,Ty)\leq \alpha d_X(x,y)$$

By the definition of continuity and translation invariance of the metric we know there exists $\delta > 0$ such that 
$$ d_X(x,y)<\delta \implies d_Y(Tx,Ty)<1$$
But I am not sure whether this imples the former condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a normed linear space and $Y=X$ with the metric $d_Y(x,y)=\frac {\|x-y\|} {1+\|x-y\|}$. Then $Y$ is a Frechet space. Let $T:(Y,d_Y) \rightarrow (X,\Vert\cdot\Vert)$ be the idenitity map. $T$ is continuous. If the inequality you have stated holds then $\|x-y\| \leq \alpha$ for all $x,y$, which is false.